# Moved Velocity jar from Bundle-ClassPath to Import-Package(Plugin dependancies) in MANIFEST.MF Then what should be the place for .vm file?

Tags: java, apache, maven, velocity

[image: Project structure]
As shown above the project structure.
In code,

```
/* Define velocity engine and template */
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty("resource.loader", "classpath");
ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class",ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
ve.init();
Template t = ve.getTemplate("fileTemplates/DCM_Default.vm");
```

Previously, velocity.jar present in /lib folder. Hence, DCM_Default.vm had found.MENIFEST.MF had entry as below in classpath,

`Bundle-ClassPath: .,`
 lib/velocity-1.7-dep.jar

Now, velocity. jar removed from classpath and it is present in Plugin dependancies in MENIFEST.MF have below changes-

`Import-Package:`
 `org.apache.velocity,`
 `org.apache.velocity.app,`
 `org.apache.velocity.context,`
 `org.apache.velocity.exception,`
 `org.apache.velocity.runtime, org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader`

I unable to find path where I have to put .vm because I faced below exception
Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'fileTemplates/DCM_Default.vm'.

can any one has any idea? Please suggest.

Comment: The exception in clearly does not find the path . You can move `fileTemplates` folder inside `src` folder.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I moved fileTemplates/DCM_Default.vm folder in src/ but it didn't work. I am using RCP as client.

Comment: Are you using maven project?

Comment: Yes. I am using Maven RCP as client project.

Comment: check my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution as below-

```
       //Define template location 
        Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
        URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path('fileTemplates/'), null));`

        /* Define velocity engine and template */
        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, fileUrl.getPath());
        ve.init();
        Template t = ve.getTemplate("DCM_Default.vm");
```

In path we need absolute path of the folder which calculate at runtime.
This is work in RCP client Plugin project.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ClasspathResourceLoader, then at runtime you must have a jar which contains fileTemplates/DCM_Default.vm. Putting it under the src directory wont guarantee that it's part of the classpath, it depends upon your IDE (which documentation should tell you how to do so).

If you know the absolute path towards your templates, you can also use the FileResourceLoader.

Answer (score 0):

Since You conform Maven Project Your Velocity file should be in `resources` folder

And your structure should be like `src-->main-->resources-->fileTemplates`

I always use below configuration to load a templates:

```
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class,file");
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute");
velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "VELLOGGER");
velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
```